# ilike search really uses its index?

Tags: index, performance, optimization, postgresql-9.2, query-performance

I have a column called nickname and have created index for it.

```
 create index test_idx on test_table using btree (nickname);
```

My query is,

```
 select * from test_table where nickname ilike '%pga%';
```

test_table is having around 100k records. when I'm doing explain, i am getting some cost which is same as before creating the index. Why is that.?

(using Postgresql 9.2)

**Edit 1:**

nickname column is character varying(100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` with a wildcard at the start of the expression can't use a btree index. In order to make that query use an index, you need to create a trigram index for which you need to [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) the [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension first.

```
create index on test_table using gin (nickname gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: I have executed, create extension pg_trgm; then, tried to create the index. But its showing, operator class "gist_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin". Have i missed some thing?

Comment: sorry, copy & paste error. For a `gin` index it needs to be `gin_trgm_ops`

Comment: Thanks. working fine. i can see the improvement. It can be applied to huge table also,? like, 10 million records are there in a table where i will use the same index and query.